# VBA #VALUE error

Tags: excel, vba

When I post the following, #VALUE is returned in the cell that should report the finisher's Division Ranking.  It should compare the finisher's division given in .Cells(lRow, 5).Value with all who finished earlier and return an appropriate ranking (numeric 1, 2 etc.).

```
   With ws
  .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.DTPicker1.Value 'Date/Time Stamp
  .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value 'Bib Number
  .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value 'First Name
  .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value 'Last Name
  .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value 'Division

  'Compute Division Ranking

  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim c As Range
  Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(lRow, 5))
  For Each c In Rng
      .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Application.Rank(c.Value, Rng, 1)
  Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark:

```
   With ws
  .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.DTPicker1.Value 'Date/Time Stamp
  .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value 'Bib Number
  .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value 'First Name
  .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value 'Last Name
  .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = CLng(Me.TextBox6.Value) 'Division

  'Compute Division Ranking

  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim c As Range
  Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(lRow, 5))
  For Each c In Rng
      .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Application.Rank(c.Value, Rng, 1)
  Next c
```

Comment: I made the suggested update, but received the following error message:   Run-time error '13': Type mismatch.  Ideas?

Comment: @user2532363 Usually the #VALUE, error is recieved when excel thinks that a number is actually text (usually because it is formatted as General, or as Text) I just through that out that to try and convert the `TextBox6.Value` to a number, make sure that your column `D` is formatted as a number if it is a number.

Comment: No joy.  Still receiving the #VALUE error.  Column D is formatted as a number.